# Docker Php and apache install Composer

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, composer-php

I want to start project and make my own framework for technical future work test, so i want to install composer for install some library, but when i execut

> docker-compose exec php bash

terminal say to me service "php" is not running

My question is : What is the right container for running composer ? apache, php ? Create a composer container ?

I have docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  apache:
    container_name: apache
    build: ./docker/apache
    links:
      - php
    ports:
      - "81:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs
  php:
    container_name: php
    build: ./docker/php
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs
    working_dir: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
```

with Docker file for apache

```
// apache/Dockerfile

FROM httpd:2.4.51

COPY apache.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/apache.conf

RUN echo "Include /usr/local/apache2/conf/apache.conf" \
    >> /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

with apache.conf

```
LoadModule deflate_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://php:9000/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/$1

    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs

    <Directory /usr/local/apache2/htdocs>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and DockerFile for PHP with COMPOSER installation

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm
WORKDIR /var/www

RUN apt-get update
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mysqli

RUN apt-get install -y autoconf pkg-config libssl-dev
RUN pecl install mongodb
RUN echo "extension=mongodb.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/mongodb.ini

COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
```

EDIT :

i change docker-composer php volumes and work_dir

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  apache:
    container_name: apache
    build: ./docker/apache
    links:
      - php
    ports:
      - "81:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs
  php:
    container_name: php
    build: ./docker/php
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs
      - ./:/var/www
    working_dir: /var/www
```

Comment: I'd normally expect to run Composer and similar dependency-management tools in the (PHP) application's Dockerfile, not in a separate container.

Comment: Okay i see thanks

Comment: [`docker compose exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_exec/) needs a running container to be executed. Maybe you're looking for [`docker compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_run/)? And I'd suggest to use separate services for "utility" containers (i.e. for running one-off composer commands).

Comment: Are oyu sure this problem is directly related to Composer itself? If your PHP container is not running, why not start it?

Comment: I change php volumes and i solved my problem